# Symfony2 Manual Redirect to Login, Preserving _security.main.target_path

Tags: php, symfony

Okay, so I know how to do this via the firewall. What I am curious about is how Symfony is doing it under the hood and how that can be replicated manually.

I have tried things like:

```
return $this->redirect( '/login', 301 );
```

But when I do that, it loses the

```
_security.main.target_path
```

And thus, when the user logs in, they are no longer redirected to the page they were on.

How do I redirect to login in a manner which replicates the firewall and thus preserves

```
_security.main.target_path
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code

add setting in your security.yml file

```
#app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                target_path_parameter: redirect_url
```

your login form must have following input tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="account" />
```

like your form

```
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="account" />

    <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: At the moment, I am outputting the $request->getSession()->get( '_security.main.target_path' ) value to the login page. If I use redirect manually, the value is missing. If the firewall redirects for me, the value is there. Would what you are suggesting preserve that? e.g. will it in one form or another, remember where it used to be? (Is that what your form_login changes do?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you "just" can throw a `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException`. The `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener` will handle it and redirect to the firewall entrypoint with the `_security.main.target_path` set.

Comment: I will test this. I like the idea.

Comment: It will work, because it is what is done by the secutrity component when the authentication fail (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/582f4753a343f230fbe18b4e9a0747d48351ddfb/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationManagerInterface.php#L32)

Comment: @YassineGuedidi it works on redirecting to login, but does not redirect back to target_path

Comment: @Basit when you are redirected to login, does `_security.main.target_path` is set in session? Check it with the profiler

Comment: No, I don't think so. but If I set it manually, which I did, then it works fine.